# Monotouch : pause application unit dialog response

Tags: ios, xamarin

How can i pause application for prevention from running next method unit client does not selected dialog buttons?
For example i am showing location update dialog for accessing location service and i want to pause my application for dialog response

```
public CLLocation UpdateUserLocation()
{
    CLLocation currentLocation = null;
    CLLocationManager LocMgr = new CLLocationManager();
    if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) 
    {

        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (6, 0)) 
        {
            LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) => 
            {
                currentLocation = e.Locations [e.Locations.Length - 1];
            };
        } 
        else 
        {
            LocMgr.UpdatedLocation += (object sender, CLLocationUpdatedEventArgs e) => 
            {
                currentLocation = e.NewLocation;
            };
        }
        LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation ();
        LocMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine (e.Error);
        };
    } 
    else 
    {
        currentLocation = null;
        Console.WriteLine ("Location services not enabled, please enable this in your Settings");
    }
    if (currentLocation != null) 
    {
        LocationDetector.Instance.UpdateCurrentArea (new MyLatLng (currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude, currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude));
    }
    return currentLocation;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly.

When you display a dialog box, you are wanting to **stop** execution of the current method from further executing **until** the user selects a dialog box response.

Once they have selected a response, you would then like to **continue** execution of the code *in the same function*, effectively achieving your 'pause' that you are after.

To achieve this in **iOS** you can use a **TaskCompletionSource**.

In the example below it shows a dialog box first, asking the user if they want some coffee and then waits for the user to respond.

Once the user responds, it then continues execution, within the same function, and displays a further message box that is dependent on the selection that the user made.

```
        UIButton objButton1 = new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        objButton1.SetTitle ("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);
        objButton1.TouchUpInside += (async (o2, e2) => {
            int intCoffeeDispenserResponse = await ShowCoffeeDispenserDialogBox();
            //
            switch (intCoffeeDispenserResponse)
            {
            case 0:
                UIAlertView objUIAlertView1 = new UIAlertView();
                objUIAlertView1.Title = "Coffee Dispenser";
                objUIAlertView1.Message = "I hope you enjoy the coffee.";
                objUIAlertView1.AddButton("OK");
                objUIAlertView1.Show();
                break;
            case 1:
                UIAlertView objUIAlertView2 = new UIAlertView();
                objUIAlertView2.Title = "Coffee Dispenser";
                objUIAlertView2.Message = "OK - Please come back later when you do.";
                objUIAlertView2.AddButton("OK");
                objUIAlertView2.Show();
                break;
            }
        });
        //
        View = objButton1;


    private Task<int> ShowCoffeeDispenserDialogBox()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<int> objTaskCompletionSource1 = new TaskCompletionSource<int> ();
        //
        UIAlertView objUIAlertView1 = new UIAlertView();
        objUIAlertView1.Title = "Coffee Dispenser";
        objUIAlertView1.Message = "Do you want some coffee?";
        objUIAlertView1.AddButton("Yes");
        objUIAlertView1.AddButton("No");
        //
        objUIAlertView1.Clicked += ((o2, e2) => {
            objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult(e2.ButtonIndex);
        });
        //
        objUIAlertView1.Show();
        //
        return objTaskCompletionSource1.Task;
    }
```