# Monotouch : Get user current lcoation

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin

How can i get use location in monotouch?
i'm trying with following code but any events does not fire(AuthorizationChanged  & LocationsUpdated)
How should i do?please advise

```
public Task<CLLocation> test()
{
    TaskCompletionSource<CLLocation> objTaskCompletionSource1 = new TaskCompletionSource<CLLocation> ();
    CLLocation currentLocation = null;
    CLLocationManager LocMgr = new CLLocationManager ();
    if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) 
    {
        LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) => 
        {
            currentLocation = e.Locations [e.Locations.Length - 1];
            locationUpdated = false;
            if (currentLocation != null && AllAreas != null) 
            {
                LocationDetector.Instance.UpdateCurrentArea (new RLatLng (currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude, currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude));
                objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult(currentLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                currentLocation = null;
                objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult(currentLocation);
            }
        };
        LocMgr.AuthorizationChanged+= (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs e) => {
            Console.WriteLine("AuthorizationChanged Fired");
        };
        LocMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) => 
        {

        };
        LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation ();
    } 
    else 
    {
        currentLocation = null;
        objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult (currentLocation);
        Console.WriteLine ("Location services not enabled, please enable this in your Settings");
    }
    return objTaskCompletionSource1.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are testing this on **iOS 8**.

For **iOS 8** you now need to **request authorization**.

So use something like the following in your **ViewDidLoad** (make LocMgr class scope level - so remove the local instance in your version):-

```
LocMgr = new CLLocationManager();
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8,0))
{
    LocMgr.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization();
}
```

Also, in order for the above to work, and for the dialog box to show you also need to add the following entry into your **info.plist**:-

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<value>{some message that will be shown to the end-user}</value>
```

**Update 1:-**

Code that I am using:-

In **ViewDidLoad**:-

```
        LocMgr = new CLLocationManager ();
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
            LocMgr.RequestWhenInUseAuthorization ();
        }

        UIButton objButton1 = new UIButton (UIButtonType.RoundedRect);
        objButton1.SetTitle ("Click Me", UIControlState.Normal);
        objButton1.TouchUpInside += (async (o2, e2) => {
            CLLocation objLocationInfo = await Test1();
            Console.WriteLine("Completed");
        });
        this.View = objButton1;
```

And the Test1 function:-

```
    public Task<CLLocation> Test1()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<CLLocation> objTaskCompletionSource1 = new TaskCompletionSource<CLLocation> ();
        CLLocation currentLocation = null;
        if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) {
            LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) => {
                currentLocation = e.Locations [e.Locations.Length - 1];
                locationUpdated = false;
                //if (currentLocation != null && AllAreas != null) {
                if (currentLocation != null) {
                    //LocationDetector.Instance.UpdateCurrentArea (new RLatLng (currentLocation.Coordinate.Latitude, currentLocation.Coordinate.Longitude));
                    objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult (currentLocation);
                } else {
                    currentLocation = null;
                    objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult (currentLocation);
                }
            };
            LocMgr.AuthorizationChanged += (object sender, CLAuthorizationChangedEventArgs e) => {
                Console.WriteLine ("AuthorizationChanged Fired");
            };
            LocMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) => {
                Console.WriteLine("AHH Failed");
            };
            LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation ();
        } else {
            currentLocation = null;
            objTaskCompletionSource1.SetResult (currentLocation);
            Console.WriteLine ("Location services not enabled, please enable this in your Settings");
        }
        return objTaskCompletionSource1.Task;
    }
```

Your need these also at class level:-

```
    private bool locationUpdated = false;
    private CLLocation currentLocation = null;

    private CLLocationManager LocMgr;
```

Remember you need to edit your **info.plist** as well.

If you then run the example putting a breakpoint at the `Console.WriteLine("Completed");` you should then be able to inspect `objLocationInfo` and see that it has a location.

Comment: I changed LocMgr to global but events does not triggering :(

Comment: @Chris If you send an email, I will send you my version that was modified from yours? It only included the changes I made above though, but it was working for me on iOS 8.

Comment: Can you please add complete code of retrieving user location?

Comment: it's showing dialog box but my events does not trigering

Comment: Thanks , i'm trying with your codes , Can i use my class contractor instead of the viewDidLoad?
Because i have separate non-view class for it

Comment: @Chris - You can do whatever you want with the code.  It is meerly here to illustrate an example of it working, just like the other answer I gave on your [other question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535738/monotouch-pause-application-unit-dialog-response).  Try and see.

Comment: Everything is good but i dont know why my events not firing ,i created break point into LocationsUpdated but it's non runnig never

Comment: @Chris - I am contactable outside this website as well if you want to outsource anything as it sounds like something else is happening in your specific scenario.  Remember to accept answers also on this site as well if your happy with the answers given.